# Absence of installing ubuntu alongside windows during new installation

Tags: installation, 13.04

I am using a company's laptop which has a single partition. Only 900 MB is achieved after shrinking using disk management tool in windows.

I tried to install both  13.04 and 12.04.3 versions. But none of them showed the traditional option of installing Ubuntu alongside Windows. The reason I can't mess with company's laptop and I am dying without Ubuntu.

I hope that somebody can help me resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

900M is too small for an Ubuntu desktop install.  You would be better off with a persistent USB or a full install to USB (still can be done on a 4G stick without swap).  USB3 sticks would be ideal, but USB2 sticks work OK, with some performance reduction.

---

If you have msdos partitioning, you are limited to only 4 primary partitions, and if you already have 4, you cannot create anymore, so maybe the side by side option is not offered.  You would need to backup a partition, delete it, then remake it and all free space as an extended partition, into which you may add logical parititions as needed.  Ubuntu does not care if it is on a logical partition.  But if you really don't have the room anyway, why bother.

Comment: thanks. I guess it is due to active bitlocker on partition. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: one more thing. usb is okay but i had like to install on my HDD only. Also somebody please tell me, what can be possible reason for ubuntu to not showing option of installing Ubuntu alongside Windows. Thanks.